# How to request predicted points for each patient based on nomogram in RMS?

Tags: survival, prediction, cox-model, rms

I am generating nomogram for a survival analysis project using RMS package of R. A PI of the project would like to have predicted points for each patient in the sample predicted by the nomogram. Is there a function or function option in RMS or in R that I can use to generate the predicted points? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require(rms)
dd <- datadist(mydata); options(datadist='dd')
f <- cph( . . . )
n <- nomogram(f, ...)
print(n)    # prints point tables
plot(n)     # draw nomogram
```

Comment: The way the site is set up you give thanks by upvoting an answer or comment or choosing it as a preferred answer.